# Is there a way to hide preview for monaco?

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a for monaco config `monaco.d.ts` so that the preview can be hided(the empty area  on the right in the below picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is called the "minimap" and can be switched on and off in the editor settings. See the [editor options](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditorminimapoptions.html) for this part.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the Question for the React version:

```js
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react';

<Editor
  options={{
    minimap: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  }}
/>
```

For the latest documentation please refer to the [offical docs](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html).